# React hooks - OnClick show only the clicked item

Tags: reactjs

I want that if I click on the button for one of those users, a second Ajax call get triggered and shows only that user, which is clicked.

For this I tried the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function UserTile ({ setID, newID }) {    
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([])

  const fetchResource = async (setID) => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.randomuser.me/'
    )
    console.log(response.data.results)
    setResources(response.data.results)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResource()
  }, [])

  resources.map((item) => {
    if (item.login.uuid === newID) {
      return (
        <div className='card__item'>
          <h2 className='card__title'>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</h2>
          <button className='btn--tile' onClick={() => setID(null)}>Back to overview</button>
              Details
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
}

export default UserTile
```

But then if I click on the button of one of the users, instead of seeing only that user, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: UserTile(...): Nothing was returned from render. This
>   usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing,
>   return null.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: UserTile function does not return anything. When using vs code your editor should have told you already before trying to run the code.

Comment: You should change the logic of the return from your UserTile component. You are missing the return.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what you tried to achieve by the question you asked. But by the looks for your code, it should be optimized and done the following way!

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, memo } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";

    const UserTile = ({ setID, newID }) => {
      const [resources, setResources] = useState([]);

      const fetchResource = useCallback(async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api.randomuser.me/");
        setResources(response.data.results);
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        fetchResource();
      }, [fetchResource]);

      const filteredResources = resources.filter(item => item.login.uuid === newID);

      if (filteredResources.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }

      return (
        <div className="card__item">
          <h2 className="card__title">
            {filteredResources.name.first} {filteredResources.name.last}
          </h2>
          <button className="btn--tile" onClick={() => setID(null)}>
            Back to overview
          </button>
          Details
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default memo(UserTile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should  have at this point

```
  resources.map((item) => {
    if (item.login.uuid === newID) {
      return (
        <div className='card__item'>
          <h2 className='card__title'>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</h2>
          <button className='btn--tile' onClick={() => setID(null)}>Back to overview</button>
              Details
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
```

replaced with

```
return (<>
  resources.map((item) => {
    if (item.login.uuid === newID) {
      return (
        <div className='card__item'>
          <h2 className='card__title'>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</h2>
          <button className='btn--tile' onClick={() => setID(null)}>Back to overview</button>
              Details
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
</>)
```

and probably use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of map