# React - Simplifying the code inside the return

Tags: reactjs

The following code shows a list of 10 users (list-view) and if you click on Details button of any of those users, it shows only that particular user (user-view).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const UserList = ({ id, setID }) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([])

  const fetchResource = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://api.randomuser.me/?results=10'
    )
    console.log(response.data.results)
    setResources(response.data.results)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResource()
  }, [])

  return (
    <ul className='card__wrapper'>
      {resources.filter(user => (id) ? user.login.uuid === id : true)
        .map(item => (
          <li className='card' key={item.name.first}>
            <div className='card__item'>
              <img className='card__image' src={item.picture.large} alt={item.name.first} />
              <h2 className='card__title'>{item.name.first} {item.name.last}</h2>
              {
                id
                ?
                  <button
                    className='card__cta'
                    onClick={() => setID(null)}
                  >
                    Back to overview
                  </button>
                :
                  <button
                    className='card__cta'
                    onClick={() => setID(item.login.uuid)}
                  >
                    Details
                  </button>
              }
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default UserList
```

While this is working fine, the code inside the return which builds both the list-view and also the user-view is a bit difficult to understand (at least for me) and also makes it hard for using different CSS classes for List- and User-view.

I'd like to simplify the code so that's easier to understand by splitting it to two different returns. 
Basically, saying that if the condition is true, return the user-view otherwise the list-view
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the rendering stuff into another function, and to make what is going to be clearer I would use two returns:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const UserList = ({ id, setID }) => {
  const [resources, setResources] = useState([]);

  const fetchResource = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.randomuser.me/?results=10");
    console.log(response.data.results);
    setResources(response.data.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResource();
  }, []);

  const renderItem = (item, isLoggedIn) => {
    return (
      <li className="card" key={item.name.first}>
        <div className="card__item">
          <img className="card__image" src={item.picture.large} alt={item.name.first} />
          <h2 className="card__title">
            {item.name.first} {item.name.last}
          </h2>
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            <button className="card__cta" onClick={() => setID(null)}>
              Back to overview
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button className="card__cta" onClick={() => setID(item.login.uuid)}>
              Details
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };

  const user = resources.find(user => user.login.uuid === id);

  if (user) {
    return <ul className="card__wrapper">{renderItem(user, true)}</ul>;
  } else {
    return <ul className="card__wrapper">{resources.map(user => renderItem(user, false))}</ul>;
  }
};

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question asked pertains to this [React hooks - OnClick show only the clicked item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680574/react-hooks-onclick-show-only-the-clicked-item/58681734)

Please find my comment for the above post, as I guess this particular issue can be solved as mentioned in the comment! In case it doesn't fix, let me know.

Comment: Hmmm, I still cannot split it.